# Sums of columns in datagrid

Tags: datagrid, livecode

I have a database and I show it in a datagrid. How can I add the sum of each column? I want each column in each row add up and finally I want to put the result into another column. Example:

```
Costo1__Costo2____RESULTADO
__2_______2__________4_____
__3_______3__________6_____
__0 ______0__________0_____
```

Comment: [COLUMNS]
Costo1: 1,2,3,4
Costo2: 2,2,3,1
result:    3.4,6,5

Answer (score 0):

If you have a MySQL or SQLite database, you can use syntax like

```
SELECT a,b FROM mytable UNION SELECT sum(a),sum(b) FROM mytable
```

After retrieving the data in LiveCode, it is easy to move the last line to the last column of the data.

Comment: I Really need make de operation in on the datagrid :S

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the entire dataset, either with the `dgData` or the `dgText`, and massage the column data in the clear. If you use the `dgText`, your data will be in tab and return delimited form, you set the `itemDel` to tab, and sum the first item in each line.

The `dgData`, which yields an array, is more compact, but do you know how to play with arrays?